# Redux UI state in Entities

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm using `normalizr` and have my `state.entities.users` branch.

In my SPA, there are pages to view users, and follow/unfollow them. We show a spinner when you are fetching a user, or waiting for the result of a follow API call.

Is there a best practice where to put UI related state?

It seems simplest to just store this in the `entities` object:

```
{
  entities: {
    [1]: {
      name: "Bob",
      followed_by_user: true
    },
    [2]: {
      isFetching: true
    }
    [3]: {
      name: "Jane",
      isUpdatingFollowing: true
    }
  }
}
```

Are there any major downsides to storing this data here? Otherwise I'll need to implement a parallel reducer shape, e.g. `state.ui.pages.users` with a lot of overlap in terms of which actions they respond to (e.g. both reducers will have to respond separately to `USER_CONSTANTS.USER_FOLLOW_SUCCESS`: one to update `state.ui.pages.users[1].isUpdatingFollowing = false`, and one to update the `state.entities[1].followed_by_user = true`, whereas in the above format I can take care of all this in one go).

Comment: Multiple reducers responding individually on maybe the same action seems to be the beauty of using Redux from separation of concern's perspective. Otherwise your reducer will keep getting bigger and bigger.

Answer (score 1):

When using redux, you should do your best to separate concerns. In your domain, `users` is a concept that seems to be independent from info about the `ui` state, so you might as well put them in different reducers.

You're free to structure your reducers the way you'd like to, but bear in mind that it is totally fine to have multiple reducers responding to shared actions. An action is not always tightly coupled to a specific reducer, even though sometimes (often) they are.

This was a good answer from the creator of redux himself to a similar question: https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/601#issuecomment-133519377.